# intermittently cassandra node is down for few seconds

Tags: cassandra

I see this behavior quite a lot, that during gossip phase one node is not discoverable and prompts a warning "INET IPADDR is now DOWN", but after few seconds it will come up. When I check the node, it is practically not down, but not discoverable via other nodes. Due to this issue, hints go off really high.

What can be the possible reason for this error and how can they be mitigated?

Comment: Are you running on a cloud (AWS, Digital Ocean, GCE)? Do you see GC messages in the logs during this DOWN period on the node which isn't responding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be a few factors that make a node appear to be DOWN. Nodes are determined to be UP or DOWN by the [gossip protocol](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/architecture/architectureGossipAbout_c.html). In some environments gossip may fail due to network congestion or long GC events. Check the `system.log` on the DOWN node. This will surface any GC events and their duration.

Increasing the `phi_convict_threshold` value in `cassandra.yaml` will decrease the sensitivity of the failure detector. Note this value should not be set above 12.

For more information check out the [failure detection and recovery](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/architecture/architectureDataDistributeFailDetect_c.html) docs.

Comment: I see, GC events. What measures can I take to tune GC? As hints are not going down to zero.

Comment: What version of Java and Cassandra are you using?

Comment: JDK1.8 and Cassandra2.2.5